# How can I make the overlapping object's outlines merge and not display on top of other objects that have the outline shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, outline

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve. I was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlTkBe4YNbo but the outlines show on top of other if the objects overlap. I tried looking through various outline shaders but couldn't find much. I found that it has something to do with Z-Depth but I am not sure how.

My reason for doing this was to replicate the Unity Editor's object selection in the project. I somehow got the gizmo partially working(using a 2nd camera) and am now stuck on object highlighting on selection.

Comment: To make this work, you unfortunately have to move away from drawing each object with a shader that outlines it at the same time it's drawn. Instead, you need to draw silhouettes of all your objects needing outlines to a separate buffer, then do edge detection on that buffer to render the outlines back on your main scene image as a post-effect.

Comment: @DMGregory Can you post this as an Answer and with more details and also preferably code?

Comment: Not just now, but [you can check out past threads on the topic for some ideas](https://forum.unity.com/threads/merge-shader.146173/). It might also help your question attract answers if you edit it to describe what kinds of things you're outlining - are they always 2D circles as shown in your diagram? Or 3D meshes / arbitrary sprite shapes with texture-based transparency, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about HLSL but i managed to hodge-podge some different scripts to make something that works.

*The only thing is*- whichever sprites you apply this to need to already have a white outline around them. I uploaded all of my UI sprites with a black fill and a white outline, and then I was able to customize both colors via the shader.

here's a little example:
[image]

and here's the code!

```
Shader "2D Overlap Outline"
{
    Properties
    {
        _ColorMain("Main Color", Color) = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
        _ColorBorder("Border", Color) = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        _MainTex("Texture to blend", 2D) = "" {}
    _StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15

        [Toggle(UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP)] _UseUIAlphaClip("Use Alpha Clip", Float) = 0
    }

        SubShader
    {
        Tags
            {
                "Queue" = "Transparent"
                "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
                "RenderType" = "Transparent"
                "PreviewType" = "Plane"
                "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
            }


        
        Pass
        {
        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite On
        ZTest Always
        Offset -1, -1
        Fog { Mode Off }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask[_ColorMask]
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            half4 _ColorMain;
            half4 _ColorBorder;

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
            };


            v2f vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;
                return o;
            }


            
            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                
                half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                
                half4 delta = _ColorBorder - _ColorMain;

               
                half4 main = _ColorMain + (color * delta);

                
                main.a = color.a;

                return main;
            }

            ENDCG
        }


        
        Pass
        {
            Offset -1, -1

            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

              
                AlphaTest Greater 0.5

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
                half4 _ColorMain;
                half4 _ColorBorder;

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert(appdata_base v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.texcoord.xy;
                    return o;
                }

                half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
                {
                    
                    half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                   
                    half4 main = _ColorMain;

                   
                    main.a = min(color.a, 1 - color.r);

                    return main;
                }

                ENDCG
            }
    }
}
```

hope it helps!

links to where i found the different scripts:

(last response)
https://forum.unity.com/threads/merge-sprites-by-color.172037/

https://blog.hamaluik.ca/posts/a-unity-4.6-ui-shader-to-ignore-depth-testing/